# DEEDLE: how to create empty data frame and add series

Tags: dataframe, addition, rows, deedle

In C#, how can I create empty data frame and add series?

I have deedle frame data from some third party api.   I need to do 'drop_duplicates' but there does't seem to be easy way to do so.
So I want to loop through and filter data myself and create new data frame.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of an input data frame, possibly with some fake data, and a data frame that you would like to obtain as a result? (i.e. specify what kind of duplicates you want to drop...)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want something like `drop_duplicates` in pandas. Deedle does not have this built-in, but you can group the rows by the values in the columns that you want to use for the comparison and then select the first row from each group:

```
let df = 
  Frame.ofRowsOrdinal [
    series [ "A" => 1; "B" => 2 ]
    series [ "A" => 1; "B" => 2 ]
    series [ "A" => 1; "B" => 3 ]
  ]

df 
|> Frame.groupRowsUsing (fun _ r ->                      // Group rows by columns A and B
  r.GetAs<int>("A"), r.GetAs<int>("B") )
|> Frame.rows                                            // Get rows of a frame as a series
|> Series.applyLevel fst (fun rows -> rows.FirstValue()) // Select first row from each group
|> Frame.ofRows                                          // Turn series back to a frame
|> Frame.indexRowsOrdinally                              // Replace index with ordinal
```

Comment: Sounds easy enough but I am not familiar with F#    Is it possible to get C# version?